# Azure Chef Automate Starter Kit

Tags: azure, chef-infra

I have a Chef Automate server in Azure that I am just starting to configure according to the Chef Docs (https://docs.chef.io/azure_portal.html). I successfully setup my credentials and logged into the Chef server, however, I was not prompted to download the starter_kit.zip file. Is there a way to manually download this file, and if so, how/where can I do that?

I also run the following command on the Chef Automate server and get a 404 Not Found error.

```
curl -X GET https://MY-AUTOMATE-SERVER.azure.com/biscotti/setup/starter-kit -k
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the Starter Kit was carried over from the Manage product to Automate. You would normally just make your own knife config file these days.

Comment: Hmmm... It's odd that they would specify it in the docs.... When I register my account, Automate also attempts to download the starter kit using the request above.

Comment: You can contact Chef Software's support team (you get a support contract as part of purchasing Automate) at support@chef.io, might be a better bet.